# Can asynchron call return to managedbean?

Tags: asynchronous, ejb, managed-bean

I am working on an application, where we have to establish, that some steps of the now synchronously working program become asynchron. We are using JSF for frontend and we have managedbeans and EJB-s.

After looking a little bit deeper into the topic, I found, that we can not make asynchronous methods in ManagedBeans, because they are not supported, so they will not work in most situations(in theory for nobody, but it worked for some people according to comments).

In theory I know that supporting an asynchronous execution means, that the asynchron funtion exection will happen with a new thread. After I started the asynchronous execution I can call other functions (like println), in the function. So does this mean, that I can call back into the managed beans as well? Or do they not support that part of the asynchronous execution? And if not, why is it not possible?

By call back I meant something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class managedBean{

@EJB
private AsynchronClass asychronClass;

  public void function(){
     asychronClass.callAsynchronFunction(this);
  }

  public void functionAsynch(){
     //do the original things
  }
}

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class AsychronClass{

  public void callAsynchronFunction(managedBean mB){
     mB.functionAsynch();
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm..no you cannot do that. First you have to mark the ejb method with @Asynchronous, but mostly, you need your ejb method to return a Future<YourObject> and the managed bean has to check for completion. There are many tutorials for this. Second, most modern JSF framework (Primefaces ecc...) supports asynchronous (ajax) call by default. Check if your frameworks has this possibility.

Comment: Thank you! We are using asynchronous ajax calls all the time, but if the execution takes too long we get an exception.